# Display Each Record in ResultSet Using Next Button JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, jdbc

I'm trying to move through and display each record retrieved from my SQL statement and then display them into TextFields.

I think I am close to getting this right however it's current displaying the last record.

I need it to navigate through clicking on the same button('Next'). I suspect I need to store the results into an Array?

It's a stock management system, just to put this into context.

Thank you for any help given :)

JAVA:

```
// Stock Search ActionListener 
            submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    try{
                    Class.forName(DRIVER);
                    // Connection to the Database
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL,"root","");

                    // Gets text from textfields and assigns them to variables
                    s1 = tfKeywords.getText();
                    // Gets ComboBox Selected Item
                    s2 = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();

                    //Creates Statement Connection
                    Statement st = con.createStatement();   

                    // SQL Statements 
                    st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+s2+" WHERE Title LIKE '%"+s1+"%'");

                    // Extracts data from statement to a result set
                    ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();

                    while (rs.next()) {
                        tfResultsTitle.setText(rs.getString("Title"));
                        tfResultsReleaseT.setText(rs.getString("ReleaseType"));
                        tfResultsType.setText(rs.getString("Type"));
                        tfResultsGenre.setText(rs.getString("Genre"));
                        tfResultsPrice.setText(rs.getString("Price"));
                        tfResultsDeal.setText(rs.getString("Deal"));
                        tfResultsInStock.setText(rs.getString("InStock"));
                        tfResultsLastRec.setText(rs.getString("LastRec"));
                        tfResultsLastSold.setText(rs.getString("LastSold"));
                        tfResultsBarcode.setText(rs.getString("Barcode"));
                    }

                    }

                    // SQL Catch block to catch errors
                    catch(SQLException s){
                    }
                    // Catch block to catch ActionListener errors
                    catch (Exception e1){   
                    } 
                };   
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it will alawys just show the last entry is because you litteraly told it to be. The call to `rs.next()` sets an internal pointer to the next row if available and returns a boolean value wheather there is an entry or not.

---

Now how can we fix your issue. There are two possibilities I can straight up think about. First you could create a new button (**Next**) which will handle the ResultSet. The way this works is that you have one button for requesting a new Resultset (connect to the database) and then **hide** this button and **show** the next button until everythin is done and then swap them again (in terms of visibility that is).

---

Another solution I would prefer myself would look similar to this:

```
private ResultSet results = null;

 submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
 {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
         // if there isn't any ResultSet or the current one is empty/done
         if(results == null || !results.next()) 
         {

             try{
             Class.forName(DRIVER);
             // Connection to the Database
             con = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL,"root","");

             // Gets text from textfields and assigns them to variables
             s1 = tfKeywords.getText();
             // Gets ComboBox Selected Item
             s2 = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();

             //Creates Statement Connection
             Statement st = con.createStatement();   

             // SQL Statements 
             st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+s2+" WHERE Title LIKE '%"+s1+"%'");

             // Extracts data from statement to a result set
             results = st.getResultSet();
             if(results.next())
             {
               setTexts(results);
             }

             }

             // SQL Catch block to catch errors
             catch(SQLException s){
             }
             // Catch block to catch ActionListener errors
             catch (Exception e1){   
             }   
         }else 
         {
              setTexts(results);
         }
     };   
 });
```

How does this work? It is simply storing the latest `ResultSet` and only issues a call to the database if there is no ResultSet at all or the current one is done.
But why can we just call our method which will print the data to the text fields without calling `results.next()` once again within the else block?

When calling `if(.. || !rs.next())` we've already called `next()` which already set the internal pointer to the right entry.

EDIT: 
How the `setTexts(ResultSet rs)` method could/should look like:

```
public void setTexts(ResultSet rs) 
{
    tfResultsTitle.setText(rs.getString("Title"));
    tfResultsReleaseT.setText(rs.getString("ReleaseType"));
    tfResultsType.setText(rs.getString("Type"));
    tfResultsGenre.setText(rs.getString("Genre"));
    tfResultsPrice.setText(rs.getString("Price"));
    tfResultsDeal.setText(rs.getString("Deal"));
    tfResultsInStock.setText(rs.getString("InStock"));
    tfResultsLastRec.setText(rs.getString("LastRec"));
    tfResultsLastSold.setText(rs.getString("LastSold"));
    tfResultsBarcode.setText(rs.getString("Barcode"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping with this. Just to clarify, what do you mean by the  setTexts(results); in the if and else

Comment: @style237 It's just an example. It is more readable if you outsource all those setter into another method ;) If this helped to solve your porblem **completely** feel free to accept the answer to help future users to find a fitting solution.

Comment: I'm terrible with Java so sorry in advance :( ... How do i call the setTexts method? from a button or? Could you maybe lay it out for me as you seem to be the boss man at this stuff ;)

Comment: @style237 you just define the `setText(ResultSet rs)` method in the same class where you set the `new ActionListener(){ ... }` and your Buttons `tfResultsTitle` ,`tfResultsRelease`, ... and so on are defined and initialized.

Comment: Thank you! Managed to figure this out. Sorry for seeming dim but you got to start somewhere right :)